# Unknown column "..." in "where clause"

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I'm having this problem with a specific task:

```
SELECT radnik.*, nalog.prioritetNalog FROM radnik
INNER JOIN nalog ON radnik.sifRadnik=nalog.sifRadnik
WHERE kvar.nazivKvar ="Zamjena klipa";
```

Results in:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'kvar.nazivKvar' in 'where clause'
```

It says this, but the column and datatable exist

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQZt4.jpg

Comment: the link is a scheme of the whole table

Comment: The table is not in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: *the column and datatable exist*, yes, but not in your Select :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing one more join, thanks for the help

```
SELECT radnik.*, nalog.prioritetNalog FROM radnik
inner JOIN nalog ON radnik.sifRadnik=nalog.sifRadnik
inner join kvar on nalog.sifKvar=kvar.sifKvar 
WHERE kvar.nazivKvar ="Zamjena klipa";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional `JOIN`:

```
SELECT r.*, n.prioritetNalog
FROM radnik r INNER JOIN
     nalog n
     ON r.sifRadnik = n.sifRadnik INNER JOIN
     kvar k
     ON k.sifkvar = n.sifkvar
WHERE k.nazivKvar = 'Zamjena klipa';
```

You can only reference columns in a query that are defined in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax :

```
SELECT column1, column2....columnN
FROM   table_name1 t1, table_name2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  CONDITION;
```

Example :

```
SELECT radnik.*, nalog.prioritetNalog 
FROM radni INNER JOIN nalog 
ON radnik.sifRadnik=nalog.sifRadnik
WHERE table_name.column_name ="Zamjena klipa";
```

Comment: What's the difference to the OP's Select?